# How to upload PDF and display the Asset Published URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

**Use Case:**
User to upload PDF from SFMC cloud page and published URL to be displayed

**Current setup:**

I have created two pages, First is the Client page where the user can upload the PDF and Second is the Server page or the processing page where the asset will be created.

**Issue:**
Pdf is getting upload in the content builder successfully with this setup but i'm not able to fetch and display the asset published url.

**Client Page Code:**

```
Please select a file to upload:
<br>
<input id="file" type="file" accept="file/*">
<br>
<button id="button">Upload</button>

<script runat="client">
  document.getElementById("button")
      .addEventListener("click", function() {
          var files = document.getElementById("file").files;
          if (files.length > 0) {
              getBase64(files[0]);
          }
      });

  function getBase64(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function() {

          //prepare data to pass to processing page 
          var fileEncoded = reader.result;
          var base64enc = fileEncoded.split(";base64,")[1];
          var fullFileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
          var fileName = fullFileName.split(".")[0];
          var assetName = fullFileName.split(".")[1];

          fetch("ServerPageURL", {  //provide URL of the processing page
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                      base64enc: base64enc,
                      fileName: fileName,
                      assetName: assetName
                  })
              })
              .then(function(res) {
                      window.alert("Success!");
              })
              .catch(function(err) {
                  window.alert("Error!");
              });
      };
      reader.onerror = function(error) {
          console.log('Error: ', error);
      };
  }
</script>
```

**Processing Page or Server Page:**

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
    //authenticate to get access token
    var authEndpoint = 'XXXXXXXXXX//' //provide API endpoint
    var payload = {
        client_id: "XXXXXX", //pass Client ID
        client_secret: "XXXXXX", //pass Client Secret
        grant_type: "XXXXX" //pass MID
    };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
    var contentType = 'application/json'

    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token //get access token
        var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url //get rest URL
    };

    //make api call to Retrieve Assets
    if (accessToken != null) {
        var assetURL = rest_instance_url + "/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1"; //Initial GET URL with page as 1
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
        var assetresponse = HTTP.Get(assetURL, headerNames, headerValues);
        var finalResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(assetresponse.Content));
        var assetCount = finalResponse.count;
        var pageCount = finalResponse.page;
        var pageSize = finalResponse.pageSize;
        var iteraterows = Math.ceil(assetCount / pageSize) + 1; //Formula to get how many times we need to call the content API
        for (var j = 1; j < iteraterows; j++) {
            var assetURLFinal = rest_instance_url + "/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=" +j; //Iterating the pages dynamically
            var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
            var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
            var assetresponseFinal = HTTP.Get(assetURLFinal, headerNames, headerValues);
            var finalResponseFinal = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(assetresponseFinal.Content));
            for (var i = 0; i < finalResponseFinal.items.length; i++) {
                var displayName = finalResponseFinal.items[i].assetType.displayName;
                if (displayName == "Image") { //checking if the type is Image
                    var publishedURL = finalResponseFinal.items[i].fileProperties.publishedURL;
                    var fileName = finalResponseFinal.items[i].fileProperties.fileName;
                    var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertDE("Test_Asset_URL", ["Asset_URL"], [publishedURL], ["Asset_Name"], [fileName]); //upserting the Image URL Link and file name
                }
            }
        }

    }
 

    } catch (error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    } </script>
```

Comment: where does it go wrong / what error are you seeing? Can you try outputting `finalResponseFinal.items` (stringified) and confirm that the upload is listed there? For some reason, you seem to be retrieving images here: `finalResponseFinal.items[i].assetType.displayName` - You said that you are uploading pdfs, are you sure that you want to get images, and that you want to retrieve by displayname? You can get to pdfs by their asset type id (127):  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/base-asset-types.html;